# Creating and writing to a file using another files name

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to automate some of my work.

I need to create a .wst file (dictation data file) with the same name as it's corresponding .DS2 (dictation file) and then populate the .WST file with the data input (author code, job type).

Perhaps I need to generate a txt then change the extension to .wst? I'm not sure...

Nothing is being created when I run the following, can anyone offer any advice?

```
import os

print('Dictation Zipper 1.0\n')

print('**Warning** What you set in the following fields will apply to ALL dictations in the current folder, please make any manual adjustments after running the tool.\n')

get_directory = input('Enter the file path where the dictations are stored, please use a NEW folder outwith the Share...\n')

author_id = input('Enter the four digit author id...\n')

jobtype_id = input('Enter the job type...\n')

for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f) #splitting file name and extension
    wst_file = open(file_name + ".wst", "w+") #creating a wst file 
    wst_file.write("[JobParameters]\nAuthorId=" + author_id + "\nJobtypeId=" + jobtype_id +"\nPriority=NORMAL\nKeyfield=\nUserfield1=\nUserfield2=\nUserfield3=\nUserfield4=\nNotes=\n")
    wst_file.close() #closing wst file
```

Comment: You're missing the directory argument to `os.listdir()`, so it's processing the current directory, not `get_directory`.

Comment: It should be `os.listdir(get_directory)`.

Comment: The part that changes the extension looks fine.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I can see that the files are generating in the current directory so at least that works! However, I have added the argument as suggested and they are still generated in the directory from where I am launching the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the directory name as an argument to `os.listdir()`. And you need to prepend the directory name to the filenames when opening the file.

```
for f in os.listdir(get_directory):
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f) #splitting file name and extension
    path = os.path.join(get_directory, file_name + ".wst")
    wst_file = open(path, "w+") #creating a wst file 
    wst_file.write("[JobParameters]\nAuthorId=" + author_id + "\nJobtypeId=" + jobtype_id +"\nPriority=NORMAL\nKeyfield=\nUserfield1=\nUserfield2=\nUserfield3=\nUserfield4=\nNotes=\n")
    wst_file.close() #closing wst file
```